# Resource for quality translations of famous American English speech/writing into Chinese?

Tags: translation, resources

I want to keep my study of Mandarin fun and engaging. One way I thought might be helpful is if there was a resource that held quality translations of famous American speeches or writing. By studying and practicing the Chinese version of famous passages, I think I could learn the language at a more lyrical level, while still working from an (english) base I can easily comprehend. This would be as opposed to studying the speeches e.g. of Mao Zedong, where I would need to learn both the English and the Chinese version.

For example, if there were a resource that took the [Top 100 Speeches](http://www.americanrhetoric.com/newtop100speeches.htm) from American Rhetoric, and translated them into Mandarin (ideally with commentary!) that would be exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: I wouldn't want that. Soundbites in one native language would sound awful in another.

Comment: Jonathan, requests for resources are off topic on this site unless there is a specific problem that needs to be solved.

Comment: Hi @xiaohouzi79, I don't think my problem can be made more specific than currently stated. If this is too open-ended for this site then please feel free to remove the question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you wanna learn Chinese by listening to its voice and let the video show English words?

Well……A pure Chinese film or TV, video CANNOT do that at all and you should involve yourself in Chinese environment to learn the language well.

However (of course)——If you insist doing so, you can see this:

[ICS Channel](http://www.icshanghai.com/live/)——This channel is playing Chinese things but translated into English version for foreign people.